# How to execute a query stored in a variable in SQL*Plus

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, sqlplus, ksh

Is there any way to pass a query to SQL*Plus through a variable?

I'm aware SQL*Plus has the capability to execute a file like:

```
sqlplus user/pass@db @filename
```

Within a kornshell script I'm trying to do:

```
query="select * from dual;"
sqlplus user/pass@db $query
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might have solution to do that BUT I can achieve the same goal using the following method.

```
[oracle@myserver Desktop]$ $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s jay/passsword@db <<! 
select * from dual; 
exit 
!


D
-
X
```

Update, you can store the returned result in a variable as shown below.

```
query="select * from dual;"
var=$($ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s jay/pass@db <<!
set pages 0
set head off
set feed off
$query
!
);
```

Comment: This is definitely a good alternative! Thank you. Strangely though, I tried encasing the variable within the exclamation marks and it doesn't work.

Comment: Although this isn't exactly what I'm looking for. This allows me to execute an SQL query from within the same script which is what I needed. If no more relevant answers come along in 30mins I will accept this answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: As I have updated, you can store your query in a variable and call inside the SQL*PLUS command section.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. I think it didn't work for me the first time because I was putting `; exit` within the variable also. That was the only difference.